# Disable a "link" tag without access to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementsbytagname

So I have a website I'm working on and in one part we have an embedded newsletter signup. The problem is that the embedded code uses all its own stylesheets which interferes with the design of the site. The embed is done through javascript so I cannot disable them until that section of the page loads.

Basically I need a `script` to disable an entire `<link>`. On top of that, the `links` don't have any `classes` or `ids` so they are hard to target.

`<link rel=​"stylesheet" type=​"text/​css" href=​"http:​/​/​www.formstack.com/​forms/​css/​3/​default.css?20130404">​`

This is one of the links I need to disable. I tried looking for something like a `getElementByType` or similar but I couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated. As long as the code disables the link that's good enough for me. Maybe there is a way to search the document for the `<link>` string and surround it with comments?

Thanks guys

PS, I'm a javascript novice and have no idea what I'm doing with js

Comment: To get all `<link>`s, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("link");`, but I'm not sure how to "disable" them. Maybe remove them with `.removeChild()`? And if the `href` is what you're targeting, you could check `.href.indexOf("http:​/​/​www.formstack.com/​forms/​css/​3/​default.css") === 0`

Comment: I'm assuming your newsletter signup form is from a different website, and you're putting it in place using an iframe?

Comment: @Kacey no it is embedded Javascript

Comment: Can you show us a demo somewhere so that we can see what is happening?

Comment: @Kacey [Link](http://www.newsecuritytechnologies.com)

Comment: Not an answer, but just an alternative. You can just add !important to your design so it won't be overridden by external design. If that external design is also have !important, load your css after document ready

Comment: Ah, I see. Your best bet would be to learn the [Constant Contact API](http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/developer-guides/api-documentation-index.html), and set up the field so that users sign up from your website, and the info is passed on to Constant Contact. Then you can design the field however you want. Trying to block it with Javascript isn't the best solution. People who don't use Javascript will see it the way it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = "http:​/​/​www.formstack.com/​forms/​css/​3/​default.css";
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets.item(i);
    if (sheet.href.indexOf(test) !== -1) sheet.disabled = true;
}
```

this will work, however it is inefficient (still) as it continues to check additional CSSStyleSheets in the CSSStyleSheetList after it has found it's match.

if you can *not care about browser support* you can use Array.prototype.some to reduce the number of ops

```
[].some.call(document.styleSheets, function(sheet) {
    return sheet.disabled = sheet.href.indexOf(test) !== -1;
});
```

see: [Array some method on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

edit:
For a mix of performance AND legacy support the following solution would work:

```
var test = "http:​/​/​www.formstack.com/​forms/​css/​3/​default.css";
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets.item(i);
    if (sheet.href.indexOf(test) !== -1) {
        sheet.disabled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: would I replace `item(i)` with `item(filepath)` ?

Comment: I added the script but it disabled all stylesheets. I just need to disable specific ones by targeting the href

Comment: @DaronSpence you need to know which one it is, you can check against the href

Comment: How is the first example inefficient? It's called `break;` to stop. And the use of `document.styleSheets` is inefficient because `<style>` elements are included.

Comment: well it is **now** after the edit, however I still think the alternative is better because document.styleSheets is MUCH less expensive than getElementsByTagName (even with additional style tags). You can perf it yourself if you want to see.

Comment: Since when was this about performance? I'd rather target what's needed than testing unnecessary things. This script is probably being run once, so the performance difference you'll see is so negligible. Like I've already said, all you have to use is `break;` in a for loop to stop the looping when the item is found.

Comment: Since when is it ***not*** about performance. the `break` in the for loop is an improvement, however the latter script *still* out preforms it. And using `for(;;)` with the `document.styleSheets` would be the best mix of performance / legacy support.

Comment: @rlemon Since when will you see a difference in speed between `document.styleSheets` and `document.getElementsByTagName("link")`? That's the only difference in speed between approaches. It's pretty obvious the OP code isn't running often, so you **won't** see or experience an improvement with `document.styleSheets`. Applying a `for` loop to either doesn't matter, **except** when you're examining **unrelated** items, like what `document.styleSheets` contains. I don't know what you're talking about legacy support for, because `.getElementsByTagName` is just as well supported.

Comment: I was talking about my solution with Array.prototype.some (ES5), and knowingly using the less performant option is never a wise choice when a (just as simple) alternative solution exists which is just as transparent and more performant. There really is no argument here, overlooking this is wrong.

Comment: @rlemon Not really. I'd rather look at the right things instead of using the wrong method to get what's needed. Even if it's 50 microseconds slower.